# Which is the newest supported version of @pnp/sp for SP 2019 (SPFx 1.4.1)?

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, spfx-webparts, 2019, pnp

When developing against SharePoint 2019 on-premises with the last supported SPFx v1.4.1, which is the newest supported version of @pnp/sp that works?

I see that v1.3.9 works - the solution can be built and executed via `gulp serve` but I don't want to try by trial and error.

I cannot find it on their documentation and it does not work with current 2.8.0 even with [typescript version workaround] (https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/SPFx-on-premises/) described on their site.

Answer (score 0):

it work fine with pnpjs v1.3

```
{
  "name": "extension-spfx-2019",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/decorators": "~1.4.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33",
    "@microsoft/sp-listview-extensibility": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-dialog": "~1.4.0",
    "@pnp/common": "^1.3.0",
    "@pnp/graph": "^1.2.8",
    "@pnp/logging": "^1.3.0",
    "@pnp/odata": "^1.3.0",
    "@pnp/sp": "^1.3.0",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^5.135.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-tslint-rules": "1.4.0",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "@types/chai": "3.4.34",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.38",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2"
  }
}
```